# Что исправить в коде, чтобы по нажатию пункты аккордеона не увеличивались?

Tags: html, css

При наведение на пункт меню он увеличивается в размерах, как это исправить

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZgGdYV)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans';
  src: url("../fonts/FiraSans-Medium.ttf");
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 460px;
}

.img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu,
.submenu {
  padding: 0;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.menu__item,
.submenu__item {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.submenu__header {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.submenu__header::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  left: 404px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 14px solid #ff8663;
}

.menu__item {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.menu__item:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #696666;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu__item:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: #4f4f4f;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e7e7e7
}

.menu__item:hover>.submenu__header {
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #ff8663;
}

.menu__item:hover>.submenu {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}

.menu__item:hover>.submenu__header {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu__item:hover .submenu__header:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 14px solid #fff;
}

.menu__item--1:hover>.submenu,
.menu__item--2:hover>.submenu,
.menu__item--3:hover>.submenu,
.menu__item--4:hover>.submenu,
.menu__item--5:hover>.submenu {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<main class="box">
  <img src="./images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="img" />
  <nav class="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu__item menu__item--1">
        <div class="submenu__header">Основы языка и как на нем говорить правильно</div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu__item menu__item--2">
        <div class="submenu__header">Функции</div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu__item menu__item--3">
        <div class="submenu__header">Обработка ошиббок и отладка</div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item menu__item--4">
        <div class="submenu__header">Объекты и массивы</div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item menu__item--5">
        <div class="submenu__header">События</div>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
          <li class="submenu__item">123</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: при наведении ваша стрелка бордером увеличивается и увеличивает контейнер

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в псевдо-элементе "::after" элемента "submenu__header".

При наведении на элемент аккордеона, ему задаётся увеличенная высота верхней рамки, из-за чего он смещается вниз

Скриншот
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: спасибо исправил добавил border-top:0;